# Mac GPU profiling?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, profiling, gpu

How can I analyze my OpenGL/C++ program and get a detailed view on what is happening in the GPU when the application is running?

I have a MacBook air running an Intel GPU (specifically an Intel HD Graphics 5000 GPU), however Intel's version of the analysis programs don't appear to be compatible with Macs (when I try to run it on my computer, it 'works' but many features are missing and it's practically useless.)

Comment: What pieces of information/features in particular are you looking for (and are presumably missing from the Intel tool)?  Frame times?  API call sequence capture?  GPU load?

Comment: API call sequence capture works with my copy of FrameAnalyzer from Intel, but that's about all I get. I can't look in depth to the calls, eg to see the amount of overhead they cost on the GPU - the options seem quite limited. Is this not something other mac users experience?

Comment: Have you tried the frame capture and various instruments offered by xcode? I find them invaluable on iOS, not used them much for OSX though.

Comment: @Columbo Xcode's frame capture doesn't work with desktop OpenGL.

Comment: @Fitzy did you manage to find anything? Most of the tools I've seen only work on Windows or Linux.